# Applying even-sized median filter in Python

Tags: python, filtering, median

My assignment is to apply a median filter of size 50x50 pixels to an image. I know how to apply the filter, but how can I specify the size of the filter when it is even? My code so far is below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
import scipy.signal as sg

#   Open data files
hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')
w1data = hdulist[0].data

hdulist2 = fits.open('xbulge-w2.fits')
w2data = hdulist2[0].data

#   Apply median filter to each image
w1_med = sg.medfilt(w1data)
w2_med = sg.medfilt(w2data)

#   Set maximum sampled galactic lat (b) and long (l)
l_max = 15
b_max = 15

#   Plot median filtered images, rescaled to galactic coordinates
plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0))
plt.imshow(w1_med, origin='lower',
           extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
           cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('W1 median filter')

plt.subplot2grid((2, 1), (1,0))
plt.imshow(w2_med, origin='lower',
           extent=[l_max, -l_max, -b_max, b_max],
           cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('W2 median filter')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Based on your comment to an answer, I think it is important to highlight even-sizedness of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] Sorry for the misunderstanding in my previous answer. Median filtering is a noise suppression technique. The result depends on the kernel dimension, which is typically a "small" odd number e.g. 3,5,7. The kernel size will give the dimension on which median gets applied. For example, with a square kernel of size 3, the algorithm carries out the operation depicted in the figure below.

[image]

So I would suggest to just try a few different kernels (e.g. 3, 5) independently on your figure size (well, almost). Then pick the one that yields the best result. This will depend on your figures.

```
sg.medfilt(w1data,kernel_size=5)
```

In addition I see this definition for medfilt:

> ```
> Signature: sg.medfilt(volume, kernel_size=None)
> Docstring:
> Perform a median filter on an N-dimensional array.
>
> Apply a median filter to the input array using a local window-size given by kernel_size. The array will automatically be zero-padded.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> volume : array_like
>     An N-dimensional input array.
> kernel_size : array_like, optional
>     A scalar or an N-length list giving the size of the median filter
>     window in each dimension.  Elements of `kernel_size` should be odd.
>     If `kernel_size` is a scalar, then this scalar is used as the size in
>     each dimension. Default size is 3 for each dimension.
>     ....
> ```

Notice the "The array will automatically be zero-padded". This is needed to fix your even sized images

Comment: I saw that in the documentation, but it also states that the kernel_size parameter must be an odd number. I did wonder if making kernel_size=49 to take into account Python's indexing-from-zero rule, but that seems huge compared to the default of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html) I think all you need to change is

```
#   Apply median filter to each image
w1_med = sg.medfilt(w1data)
w2_med = sg.medfilt(w2data)
```

to

```
#   Apply median filter to each image
w1_med = sg.medfilt(w1data, kernel_size=50)
w2_med = sg.medfilt(w2data, kernel_size=50)
```

...does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The key in your question is the *even*-sizedness of the kernel. `scipy.signal.medfilt` constrains you to use odd-sized kernels. Do a search on the Web and you will find plenty of information as to why kernels are usually odd-sized. The main reason, I believe, is centering.

For example, if you convolve an image containing a Gaussian with an even-sized Gaussian kernel - you will end-up with an image with a Gaussian with a shifted (by 1/2 pixels) center compared to the original, not convolved, image.

With regard to the median filter specifically, there is an additional reason why one may consider odd-sized kernels: having an odd number of pixels produces a unique median while having an even number of pixels would require deciding, e.g., on which pixel to use as the result: `pixel[int(size/2)]`, `pixel[int(size/2)+1]`, or the average of the two.

You cannot use `scipy.signal.medfilt` for even-sezed kernels. However, you can always write a loop to go through all pixels of the input image and extract an even-sized window "around" each pixel, and then compute the median of the pixels in that window. I quote "around" because it is not clear (=unique) how to center that window on a pixel: it will be up to you to make a decision.